# Is a Riemann-integrable function always differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be Riemann-integrable and $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$.

Is this function $F$ always differentiable? Because the antiderivative is defined as $F'=f$ right, so you would think that it always holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between integral functions and antiderivatives. Antiderivatives are defined by how they behave under differentiation. Integral functions are defined as being integrals with a variable boundary point. These are not the same thing! Your $F$, by definition, is an integral function of $f$, not an antiderivative.

The fundamental theorem of calculus now gives us sufficient conditions for when these two things do happen to coincide: if $f$ is continuous, then every integral function is also an antiderivative (and take care: even then, not every antiderivative is an integral function). That's a theorem, not a definition. Pavel R. gave you a good example why the theorem needs continuity of $f$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No. Consider $f(x)=\mathrm{sgn}\ x$ for $x\in[-1,1]$. Then $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=|x|-1$ which is not differentiable at $x=0$.